# Why run three row if the csv store tow data row?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-recorder

I made a CSV and I used it for a data driven test in Katalon.

```
x,y
house,way
1,2
```

Run the test and the test runs three times, however, I stored two valid data inputs (house, way; 1,2)?

I don't know why this happened.

Comment: help us to help you please show code?

Comment: It's solved my problem: https://forum.katalon.com/t/the-loadvars-runs-for-an-extra-csv-row-that-doesnt-exist/11073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your CVS file, its got extra line or CR at the end, use notepad to delete all empty space and line after the last character of 2nd line.  Also remember to delete and reload the file in Data Driven